# I want to fetch backend seo yoast meta

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

I want to fetch backend  seo yoast meta description in wordpress custom post type,but if yoast meta description is empty it should fetch text from  tag anybody can suggest how to do it

Comment: Fetch it in what context using what programming language?

Comment: Its for wordpress yoast plugin ,i want to implement code via functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

You get posts meta by this query:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
    
        $item['seo_meta_description']  = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_yoast_wpseo_metadesc',true);
    
        if(!empty($item['seo_meta_description'])){
           $meta_des = $item['seo_meta_description'];
        }else{
            $meta_des = get_the_content();
        }
    
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you give code for custom post type ,also can you tell me what is hard coding & coding

Comment: you can change your post type name:
'post_type'      => 'custom post type name'

Comment: can it fetch title if meta description is empty

Comment: replace get_the_content() to get_the_title()